# MySQL - get first 100 character of column in full text search (WHERE MATCH)

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the First 100 characters of an found column "text".

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE MATCH (title,text) AGAINST ("*das*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Is there a way to do it in 1 command?

Comment: look at the `mid` function: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_mid.asp

Comment: @njzk2 why not use [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)?

Comment: @Shaharyar from the doc: "MID(str,pos,len) is a synonym for SUBSTRING(str,pos,len)." So, no reason really, just I found MID before I found SUBSTRING

Comment: Yeah just read the same, first time heard about `mid` actually.

Comment: @njzk2 is MID usable in this case?
-
SELECT MID(*,1,100) FROM article WHERE MATCH (title,text) AGAINST ("*das*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) -
is not working… maybe im stupid …… maybe there is another way to do this?

Comment: If you just want the first characters of the text column returned, then`SUBSTR(text,1,100)`. (The specification for the resultset isn't very clear... i.e. what columns do want to return? in what order? Providing example data and expected resultset would help clarify the specification. Otherwise, we're just guessing.)

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the Help of njzk2 and spencer7593 and Shaharyar i found this solution:

```
SELECT  id,title,SUBSTR(text,1,100) FROM article WHERE MATCH (title,text) AGAINST ("*das*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two option to read sub part of string text value from mysql table field-

```
1 - SUBSTRING(str, pos, len)
      OR 
2 - SUBSTRING(str FROM pos FOR len)
```